# How can i get the actual filepath of a file mounted in overlayfs?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

I have a filesystem mount using `overlayfs`.

eg:

overlaymount -> `/google`  (merge of `/yahoo` and `/bing`)

Now how can i have a file `/google/a.txt`

How can i figure out the root filesystem (`/yahoo` or `/bing`) of the file `/a.txt`

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: @ZangMingJie I need a programmatic answer preferably in c